# Zurb Foundation dropdown alignment

Tags: jquery, zurb-foundation

Is there any way in Foundation Zurb to align the [**Content Dropdown**](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/dropdown.html) to the top? I'm trying to do something similar to the [**Popover**](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers) in Bootstrap that has four options of aligment. Adding html to the Foundation tooltip I think is better because it already has the top, left, right, bottom feature. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a feature that's already implemented using the data-options attribute, [see here](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/dropdown.html) for more details (under "Directions").

However, it appears you'll need at least version 5.2 for this to work.

Comment: I have another question. Now, I want to align it to top. I tried this to separate them `align:left; is_hover:true;` but didn't work. Fiddle here: **http://jsfiddle.net/kCLHW/1/**. Thanks.